# @Valid Annotations not working from Junit 5 with mockito while testing spring boot services

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation

I am having a tough time to get the validation annotations set up right for testing from Spring Boot Services using Jnit 5

Service Interface

```
@Validated
public interface UsersQueryService {

     Users getById(@ValidIdentifier Long id);
    
}
```

Unit Test

```
@Test
void getById_invalid_id() {
    assertThrows(UsersException.class, () -> {
        Long invalid_id = 0l;
        usersService.getById(invalid_id);
    });
}
```

I tried to read through lots of posts, but all are covering the implementation and not matching with my usecase. In one blog, i found the below code to register method validation post processor, but that is also not working. kindly suggest the right way to get this working

```
@TestConfiguration
    static class MethodValidationConfig {
        @Bean
        public MethodValidationPostProcessor bean() {
            return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
        }
    }
```

**Note**: I am only doing service tests and hence not validating the request flow

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
class UsersQueryServiceTests
```

Comment: Do you have the app configured otherwise correctly with JSR303 annotations and working so only the test fails to use correct validator?

Comment: yes, the Junit5 test cases are executing and the annotations are working fine in the api flow tested using postman, however the validations are not working from the test cases alone